# Error with facebook API Marketing request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have a problem with facebook API Marketing when I try to do this post request: **act_ad_account_ID/users**

I try to give to another user an analyst access to account, but it returns me error: **(#10) Application does not have permission for this action**

It happens only with **one** account, great number of other accounts works fine. **All permissions of application are set correctly.**

Cant find any description of this error. Could you please help me?

**Updated:**

Found that the error occurs when the ad account belongs to the partner, even if the admin role in the ad account. 
So I have a question:  Is there a way to add a advertiser to the add account of the partner of business owner? If I have all permissions of owner account?

Comment: Does the access token you generated have the business management permission granted? Is it for an admin user of the business?

Comment: Yes, sure. Token has all needed permissions and this token belongs
to user with admin role. These permissions works well for another users. But there is an error in this case.